# Remove the '_id' from the return of MongoDB mongoengine with python Flask

Tags: python, mongodb, flask-mongoengine

I am using the mongoengine for my python flask application and using the Custom ORM for the project.

I am facing an issue in the GET API where I am fetching the list of the asset data which is stored in my database and when I am retrieving the data it shows me data like:
code,

```
           {
               "message": "done",
               "result": {
                   "asset": [
                              {
                                  "_id": {
                                      "$oid": "5fa4fb9ea33244b15c6605bc"
                                  },
                                  "asset_download_link_android": "https://link",
                                  "asset_download_link_ios": "https://link",
                                  "asset_download_link_mac": "https://link",
                                  "asset_download_link_windows": "https://link,
                                  "asset_id": 1,
                                  "asset_name": "car_exhibition_1",
                                  "asset_size": "100MB",
                                  "asset_thumbnail_url": "https://link",
                                  "asset_version": "1.0.0",
                                  "created_at": {
                                      "$date": 1604647838316
                                  },
                                  "email": "xyz@gmail.com"
                              },
                          ]
                      },
                      "status": 200
                  }
```

Now,

```
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5fa4fb9ea33244b15c6605bc"
            }
```

which has been created by my ORM and due to this "$" sign I can't proceed because my object can assign a variable with the special character in the beginning. So, please anyone can help me that how can I get the response without the $oid field in the response.

The code I am using to get the response is,

```
                  assets =  collection_name.objects.all()
                  return_val = jsonify({"message" : "done" , "status" : status_code, "result" :                                                                
                                       {"asset" : assets}})
                  return return_val, status_code
```

Comment: Do you need the `_id` in your frontend? Or possibly; instead of fixing the `$oid` name (or removing the id with `del asset['_id']` in a loop), make your frontend work properly with `$oid`. What's the code that barfs out on the `$`?

Comment: I need to work with the unity as in the frontend but they can't take the "$oid" as in the variable because the special character can't allow us to move forward. So, need to remove in the response

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the inner `assets` list and remove any keys that contain keys with `$` beneath them:

```
import json
import pprint

foo = json.loads("""
{
   "message": "done",
   "result": {
       "asset": [
                  {
                    "_id": {
                      "$oid": "5fa4fb9ea33244b15c6605bc"
                    },
                    "asset_download_link_android": "https://link",
                    "asset_download_link_ios": "https://link",
                    "asset_download_link_mac": "https://link",
                    "asset_download_link_windows": "https://link",
                    "asset_id": 1,
                    "asset_name": "car_exhibition_1",
                    "asset_size": "100MB",
                    "asset_thumbnail_url": "https://link",
                    "asset_version": "1.0.0",
                    "created_at": {
                      "$date": 1604647838316
                    },
                    "email": "xyz@gmail.com"
                  }
              ]
          },
          "status": 200
      }
""")

for asset in foo['result']['asset']:
    del asset['_id']
    del asset['created_at']
    
pprint.pprint(foo)
```

Results in:

```
{'message': 'done',
 'result': {'asset': [{'asset_download_link_android': 'https://link',
                       'asset_download_link_ios': 'https://link',
                       'asset_download_link_mac': 'https://link',
                       'asset_download_link_windows': 'https://link',
                       'asset_id': 1,
                       'asset_name': 'car_exhibition_1',
                       'asset_size': '100MB',
                       'asset_thumbnail_url': 'https://link',
                       'asset_version': '1.0.0',
                       'email': 'xyz@gmail.com'}]},
 'status': 200}
```